# show a quotient ring is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

let q be a prime number which divides integer t,
how can we show quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}$[$\sqrt{t}$]/(q, $\sqrt{t}$) is a field?

Comment: Well, there are two obvious strategies: show that the ideal $(q,\sqrt{t})$ is maximal, or directly exhibit inverses in the quotient ring. Have you tried to do either of these? What difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: It's isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/(q)$

Comment: I use the second method by showing each nonzero element in the quotient ring has a unit.  But encounter some difficult to find the unit.

Comment: Ok, how do you characterize the nonzero elements of the quotient ring? You'll get better responses on this site if you include detailed descriptions of what you've tried in your question.

Comment: I take an arbitrary nonzero element  y = a + ( q, $\sqrt{t}$ ) in the quotient ring. Let's say  a = c + d$\sqrt{t}$. Then WTS $\exists$ z =  b +  ( q, $\sqrt{t}$ ) such that zy = ab + ( q, $\sqrt{t}$ ) = 1+ ( q, $\sqrt{t}$ ).  Then it suffices to show ab - 1 $\in$ ( q, $\sqrt{t}$ ).   i.e. ( c + d$\sqrt{t}$)( e + f$\sqrt{t}$ ) $-$ 1  =  qw + $\sqrt{t}$v  for some w,v $\in$ $\mathbb{Z}$[$\sqrt{t}$].  But I feel difficult to find integers e and f to make this equation hold.

Comment: $\!\bmod q,\sqrt t\!:\ \,  q\equiv 0\equiv\sqrt t \,\Rightarrow\  a + b\sqrt t \,\equiv\, a\bmod q\ \ \ $

Comment: not quite understand it

Comment: By the prior comment, every element in your quotient ring is equivalent to an integer; and since also $q = 0$  your quotient ring is an image of $\,F=\Bbb Z/q\,$, necessarily $F$ since $1\not\in(q,\sqrt t).\ \ $

Comment: See also [this answer.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374203/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{t}]$ has the form $x=a+b\sqrt{t}$ for uniquely determined integers $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. So define a map $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{t}]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$ by $$x\mapsto a\pmod{q}.$$

Check that this is surjective and $\ker(\varphi)=(q,\sqrt{t})$. Now think about the first isomorphism theorem.