# Ideal of $\mathbb Z[x] $ generated by $\mathit x^2+1$ and $ 3x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $\mathit I $$\,$ be the ideal of   $\mathbb Z[x] $ generated by $\mathit x^2+1$ and $ 3x+1$. 
Find the positive integer $\mathit n$ such that $\mathit I$ $\cap \mathbb Z$ = $\mathit n$$\mathbb Z$

I find $(\mathit x^2+1)(9)+ (3x+1)(-3x+1)= 10 $, So It is expected that 'n =10'
But I can't find for n=1, 2, 5

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $\ (x^2\!+\!1)f + (1\!+\!3x)g = n\!\iff\! \bmod x^2\!+\!1\!:\ 1\!+\!3x\mid n.\,$ But $\,\Bbb Z[x]/(x^2\!+\!1)\cong \Bbb Z[i]\,$ so

$$ 1\!+\!3i\mid n\ \, {\rm in}\, \ \Bbb Z[i]\iff \underbrace{\dfrac{n}{1\!+\!3i}\in \Bbb Z[i]\iff \dfrac{n(1\!-\!3i)}{10}\in\Bbb Z[i]}_{\large \text{rationalize denominator}}\iff \color{#c00}{10\mid n}\ \ {\rm in}\ \ \Bbb Z\qquad$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2374203/242) for more, include a method using Hermite normal form basis.

Comment: Sorry, What  dose "$ \bmod x^2\!+\!1\!:\ 1\!+\!3x\mid n.\,$" mean??
I know only $\bmod $use when '$a \equiv b (\bmod k)$)'

Comment: Is  " $\bmod x^2\!+\!1\!:\ 1\!+\!3x\mid n.\,$" means that   $(1+3x)\mathit g \equiv n\ (\bmod (3x+1))$$\,$??

Comment: @sss It means exactly the same as the first equation to its left, i.e. mod that out by $\,x^2+1.\,$ You can skip  straight to the quotient ring if your prefer. I was simply trying to motivate it additionally with equivalent congruence notation. Generally $\,a\mid b\,$ in $R\,$ means $\,ar = b\,$ for some $\,r\in R,\,$ just like in $\,R = \Bbb Z\ \ \ $