# Prime ideals of a certain form

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

The author of a solution of an earlier problem indicated that, writing the ideal of the integer ring $O_K$ of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, $$(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$$ in the form $$\{x+y\sqrt{-5}\mid y\equiv x\ \bmod3\}$$ we immediately see that this ideal is prime. I failed to immediately see why that is true.

Comment: I think that 'immediately' is a bit over the top. Maybe we can see it after writing out the details of what it would *mean* for the ideal to be prime or not? Did you try that?

Comment: @Vincent I do know how to show that an ideal is prime. I only asked because I wondered if the latter form allowed us to apply the same principal to other ideals of form (p,a+sqrt(d)) for arbituary p prime, a and d and immediately see that they are prime.

Comment: That is an interesting question. Obvious it would not be the case for all ideals, so it would be nice to get a closer look at for which ideals it works or not.  I'll think a bit about it

Comment: @Vincent It is fairly "immediate" if one knows the pertinent results - see my answer (that argument works very generally and only need be made once).

Comment: A hyperlink for context would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

Both versions immediately show that the ideal $I = (3, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ is prime: given any element $a + b \sqrt{-5}$ we find
$$ a+b\sqrt{-5} = a - b + (b + b \sqrt{-5}) \equiv a-b \bmod I. $$
Thus ${\mathbb Z}[\sqrt{-5}]/I \simeq {\mathbb Z}/3{\mathbb Z}$, hence $I$ is prime since the quotient is an integral domain (even a field, so the ideal is maximal).

Comment: More generally, an ideal $I$ that has prime index $p$ in a commutative ring $R$ has to be a maximal ideal in $R$ since $R/I \cong \mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$. The converse of course is false (such as $(3)$ in $\mathbf Z[i]$ or $(11)$ in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, which are maximal ideal despite having non-prime index).

Answer (score 0):

**Key Idea**  the ideal $\,(3,1+\sqrt{-5})\,$ is already a *module in Hermite normal form*, which makes everything very easy. Write $\,R = \Bbb Z[w],\,\ \bar R = R/I,\,\ I=(3,1\!+\!w),\,\ w = \sqrt{-5}.\,$ By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/608414/242), since $\,3\mid N(1+w) = 6,\,$ we deduce that $I = (3,1+w) = [3,1+w] = 3\Bbb Z + (1+w)\Bbb Z.\,$  But it is trivial to test module membership given such a *triangularized* basis, namely
$$\begin{align} \overbrace{a+bw}^{\large  a-b\ +\ \color{#0af}{(1+w)b}}\!\!\!\!\!\!&\in I = 3\Bbb Z + \color{#0af}{(1\!+\!w)\Bbb Z}\\
\iff\ \ \ a\!-\!b&\in I\\
\iff\ \ \ a\!-\!b &\in 3\Bbb Z 
\end{align}\qquad$$

so $\ a\!+\!bw\bmod I\, =\, a\!-\!b\,\bmod 3,\, $ so $\,\bar R = R/I\cong \Bbb Z/3\,$ (so $I$ is prime, in detail:

$\qquad\quad  h: \Bbb Z \to \bar R\,\color{#0a0}{ \ {\rm is\ surjective\  (onto)}}\,$ by $\bmod I\!:\  a\!+\!bw\equiv a\!-\!b\in \Bbb Z$
$\qquad\quad \color{#c00}{\ker h = 3\,\Bbb Z}^{\phantom{|^|}}\! $ follows by $\,b=0\,$ in above displayed equivalences).

**Remark** $ $ The criterion generalizes to an ideal test for modules $\rm\,[a,b\!+\!c\:\!\omega]\,$ in the ring of integers of a quadratic number field, e.g. see section 2.3 Franz Lemmermeyer's notes [linked here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133515/242).

This is a special case of module *normal forms* that generalize to higher degree number fields, e.g. see the discussion on **Hermite and Smith normal forms** in Henri Cohen's $ $ *A Course in Computational Number Theory*.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "The author of a solution of an earlier problem indicated that, writing the ideal of the integer ring $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, $$(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$$ in the form $$\{x+y\sqrt{-5}\mid y\equiv x\ \bmod3\}$$ we immediately see that this ideal is prime. I failed to immediately see why that is true.

**Answer:** In the case of the ring $A:=\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]:=\mathbb{Z}[t]/(t^2+5)$ and the ideal  $I:=(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$ you may also use an elementary calculation with ideals in the ring $R:=\mathbb{Z}[t]$. You may check that there is an equality of ideals in $R$:

$$(t^2+5,3,t+1)=(3,t+1).$$

From this you get the isomorphisms

$$A/I \cong R/(3,t+1)\cong \mathbb{Z}/(3)$$

which is a field, hence $I \subseteq A$ must be a prime ideal.